# Declare multiple variables in single formula

Tags: crystal-reports, report

In my report I want to declare a lot of variables, initialize them, and use them in report text objects. I don't want to create a separate formula for each variable declaration. Is there a way to declare multiple variables in one place?

Answer (score 0):

Just declare and initialize them within only one formula.

Comment: I did that but didn't find a way to use each individual variable from the formula into different individual report text objects.

Comment: Sorry, I only recognized declaration and initialization of variables from your questions. Afaik there has to be one formula per variable to use their value as output in the report.

Answer (score 0):

you can set up one formula like this and maybe call it INITVARS

```
numbervar a :=2;
numbervar c :=5;
stringvar b :="Stack OVer Flow";
```

It must be placed in your report canvas somewhere. Hidden or you can place it somewhere that you want one of the variables to be seen and place that variable at the end of the formula.

To call one or more of the variable you then have to make it available in the new formula like this for example..

```
numbervar a;
numbervar c;
a*c
```

Not sure of a better way to do that because you still have to re-type the variable everytime. However you only have to go to the INITVAR formula to set values.

you should probably do some research on Evaluation Time functions as well depending upon what your goal is
BeforeReadingRecords;
WhileReadingRecords;
WhilePrintingRecords;
EvaluateAfter;